# jQuery: помогите разобрать JSON строку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно разобрать JSON данные, которые приходят с сервера - вывод console.log(data) такой:

```
Object {html: "<a href="#" title="Фрукты">Фрукты</a>
<a href="#" title="Овощи">Овощи</a>   ", data: Object}
```

На сервере массив выглядит следующим образом:

```
 Array
(
    [html] => Фрукты   Овощи     
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1parametr] => Магазин 1
            [2parametr] => Магазин 2
        )

)
```

Дальше этот массив я преобразую в строку:

```
$arr_to_json = json_encode($arr_json, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

Нужно, получая эти параметры в jQuery, записать значение ключа `[html]` в переменную `var html`, а `data` разобрать по соответствующим переменным, т.е. записать в переменные по ключам массива `1parametr` и `2parametr` значения `Магазин1` и `Магазин2`

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj.html); // будет выведен html элемент твоего массива
```

Comment: пишет VM1517:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: возможно ошибка в вашем серверном коде

Comment: Может ли быть ошибка в серверном коде, если я в console.log(data) вижу приходящие данные? `Object {html: "<a href="#" title="Фрукты">Фрукты</a>
<a href="#" title="Овощи">Овощи</a>   ", data: Object}`

Comment: если закодировать указанный в вопросе массив json_encode получится совсем другая строка, нежели отписанная вами, возможно вы ее уже обработали

Comment: Учитывая что он видит в консоли, вопрос заключается в том чтобы "присвоить значение переменной", что очень странно. Осмелюсь предположить (относительно стандартный вариант), что насамом деле запрос асинхронный, а переменная локальная, и мы не знаем на какой вопрос отвечаем.